# pgfplots and using axis cs to add points

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I am trying to mark two inflection points using a `foreach` loop in a `pgfplot`, but it isn't working.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.10}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\infx}{1/sqrt(2)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\infy}{exp(-.5)}
  \begin{axis}[
    xmin = -3,
    xmax = 3,
    ymin = -0.1,
    ymax = 1.05,
    domain = -4:4
    ]
    \addplot[blue, samples = 500, smooth] gnuplot {exp(-x^2)};

    \foreach \x/\y in {\infx/\infy, -\infx/\infy}{
      \draw[red] (axis cs: \x, \y) circle[radius = .025];
    }
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I am being told:

```
Undefined control sequence.^M
<argument> axis cs: \x ^M
                       , \y ^M
l.34   \end{axis}^M
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The variables need to be expanded since pgfplots don't draw a path immediately but instead collects them. When collecting, it only sees `\x` and `\y` and collects them. When it comes to draw them \x and \y are not defined hence you get an error.

If you had one variable, you could use `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` but since you have two indices you need to expand them yourself.

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat = 1.10}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\infx}{1/sqrt(2)}
  \pgfmathsetmacro{\infy}{exp(-.5)}
  \begin{axis}[
    xmin = -3,
    xmax = 3,
    ymin = -0.1,
    ymax = 1.05,
    domain = -4:4
    ]
    \addplot[blue, samples = 500, smooth] gnuplot {exp(-x^2)};

    \foreach \x/\y in {\infx/\infy, -\infx/\infy}{
      \begingroup\edef\temp{%
           \endgroup\noexpand\draw[red] (axis cs: \x, \y) circle[radius = .025];}\temp
    }
  \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```