# Why does it matter where I'm trying to call my \foreach loop from?

Tags: pgfplots, foreach

I was trying to post a solution to [How can I draw 25 horizontal lines instead of these 25 marked samples?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/173795/22413), but I got stuck with a `\foreach` loop which wasn't behaving as I expected it to.

Here's my first attempt:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
\begin{axis}
  [
    height=5cm,
    width=6cm,
    scale only axis=true,
    %
    xlabel={\(\alpha\) in \si{\degree}},
    ylabel={\(\sin{(\alpha)}\)},
    %
    xtick=\empty, 
    ytick=\empty, 
    xticklabels={,,}, 
    yticklabels={,,}, 
    xmajorgrids={false}, 
    ymajorgrids={false}
  ]
  \addplot+[domain=0:360, 
            samples=25, 
            only marks, 
            mark=-] 
           {sin(x)};
  \foreach \myn in {1,...,25}
    {
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\myx}{360/(25-1) * (\myn-1)}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\myy}{sin(\myx)}
      \draw (axis cs:0,\myy) -- (axis cs:360,\myy);
    }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

I get an error:

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> axis cs:0,\myy 

l.41 \end{axis}

?
```

I wasn't expecting such an error.  Nevertheless, I came up with a clunky work around.  Here's my 2nd attempt which works quite well (though a bit clunky):

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp,siunitx}

\makeatletter
\def\aedrawline#1{%%
  \edef\mycontent{#1}
  \expandafter\ae@drawline\mycontent\@nil}
\def\ae@drawline#1,#2,#3\@nil{%%
  \draw (axis cs:#1,#3) -- (axis cs:#2,#3);
  }
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
\begin{axis}
  [
    height=5cm,
    width=6cm,
    scale only axis=true,
    %
    xlabel={\(\alpha\) in \si{\degree}},
    ylabel={\(\sin{(\alpha)}\)},
    %
    xtick=\empty, 
    ytick=\empty, 
    xticklabels={,,}, 
    yticklabels={,,}, 
    xmajorgrids={false}, 
    ymajorgrids={false}
  ]
  \addplot+[domain=0:360, 
            samples=25, 
            only marks, 
            mark=-] 
           {sin(x)};
  \foreach \myn in {1,...,25}
    {
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\myx}{360/(25-1) * (\myn-1)}
      \pgfmathsetmacro{\myy}{sin(\myx)}
      \aedrawline{0,
                  360,
                  \myy}
    }
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

All's good until @Tarass posts [an answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/173799/22413) which is very similar in concept to mine but avoids the clunky work around of my attempts:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots,amsmath}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern,textcomp,siunitx}

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
\begin{axis}
  [
    height=5cm,
    width=6cm,
    scale only axis=true,
    %
    xlabel={\(\alpha\) in \si{\degree}},
    ylabel={\(\sin{(\alpha)}\)},
    %
    xtick=\empty, 
    ytick=\empty, 
    xticklabels={,,}, 
    yticklabels={,,}, 
    xmajorgrids={false}, 
    ymajorgrids={false},
    after end axis/.code={%%
      \foreach \myn in {1,...,25}
        {
          \pgfmathsetmacro{\myx}{360/(25-1) * (\myn-1)}
          \pgfmathsetmacro{\myy}{sin(\myx)}
          \draw (axis cs:0,\myy) -- (axis cs:360,\myy);
        }
    }
  ]
  \addplot+[domain=0:360, 
            samples=25, 
            only marks, 
            mark=-] 
           {sin(x)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Could someone explain what's going on here?  In particular, why it that when the `\foreach` loop is called within the `axis` environment it is *forgetful* and needs instead to be processed from `after end axis`?

Comment: Have you seen percusse answer on my post [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/172917/pgfplots-and-using-axis-cs-to-add-points)?  It may be of some use.

Comment: @dustin Thank you for the link.  I think that means my question should be closed as duplicate.

Comment: I thought about that but wanted to see if that helped first before I did.

Comment: @dustin Except that it doesn't explain why Tarass's approach worked.

Comment: I may be wrong but it looks like it works since there is only one looped value `sin(\i)`.  In your code, you have `\myy` and `\myx` so you have to expand.  You could probably use `\pgfplotsinvokeforeach` with Tarass.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess that the problem is that TikZ/PGF doesn't like

```
\draw (axis cs:0,\myy) -- (axis cs:360,\myy);
```

because it wants to see “explicit” coordinates. Using the usual trick for expanding things it seems to work:

```
  \foreach \myn in {1,...,25}
    {
     \pgfmathsetmacro{\myx}{360/(25-1) * (\myn-1)}
     \pgfmathsetmacro{\myy}{sin(\myx)}         
     \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup
       \noexpand\draw (axis cs:0,\myy) -- (axis cs:360,\myy);}%
     \x
    }
```

[image]

Why the difference with Tarass's code? I can't explain.

Comment: Why the `\begingroup` ... `\endgroup`?  It seems to work fine without it.  Since it's only a local definition within a `\forloop` it shouldn't be overwriting anything outside of the loop.  Or am I missing something?

Comment: @A.Ellett This way what `\x` is defined to be (if it's defined) is unimportant and its (re)definition will disappear as soon as it's expanded.